# How to make my neural network fit well on both training and validation datasets

Tags: neural-networks, overfitting

My classification model (10 layers of MLP) has to overfit training data to perform well (measured by loss and other metrics), however this overfits and perform badly on validation data; without overfitting (smaller model, regularization, etc.), both data fit badly.

Data are collected using same process and randomly split to training and validation with 5:1 ratio, I had verified their distributions are the same.

Why does this happen and what should i do for this situation? Thank you.